# is it possible to stop the cts and save the current logs

Tags: android, android-cts

I am running android-cts . The commands I run are mentioned below,
cts-tf

run-cts --plan --cts-camera
It is being running for two days . How do I stop the current task and save the existing logs .
Also it is mentioned in documentation ,that the cts logs will be stored in
CTS_ROOT/android-cts/results/start_time.zip
But I dont see a start_time.zip in the location specified .

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways by which you can stop the CTS invocation and result will be generated of your runs,

1. Unplug the USB Cables from the devices, this will make tradefed to not detect any device and once timeout occurs, it will generate result on testcases and modules it ran.
2. Kill command, just write the kill in the tradefed, and it will kill and stop the invocation threads for the runs. once that is done, it will generate the result but make sure not to give kill command more than 1 or else it will exit from tradefed without generating the result.